# Javascript page color changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bunch of code to change the colour of text using a dropdown menu

```
$(function() {
  $(".colorSelect").change(function() {
    $("body").attr('class', '');
    $(".colorSelect").each(function() {
      $("body").addClass($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

I'm know that having it on the body class is not a great idea so I tried this but it didn't work.

```
    $(function() {
  $(".colorSelect").change(function() {
    $("color").attr('class', '');
    $(".colorSelect").each(function() {
      $("color").addClass($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

I then put a class on each element I wanted to change which didn't work.

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong? If your not sure what I'm asking, I'm asking how do i change it from appending to body. I have it in a preview.html can i just append to this?

**Edit**

Ive just tired the id selector with .color and that has not worked. No idea why!

Sam

Comment: *"I'm know that having it on the body class is not a great idea"* Why not? Certainly removing all classes (`$(body).attr('class', '')`) is probably a bad idea, but managing classes on it for setting page color is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Sorry, Its bad becuase its going across all the rest of my pages, Could have it just stay on the preview page

Comment: With `$("color")` you select all `<color>` tags which are btw no valid mark-up tags. If you want to select a certain class use the `$(".class")` selector like you have with `$(".colorSelect")`. You could just use divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with most of the answers is they miss the side-effect of `removeAttr('class')`, which is to remove all other classes including "color". I would suggest only changing known classes:

```
$(function () {
    $(".colorSelect").change(function () {
        $(".color").removeClass("red, blue").addClass($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qwrcxzat/2/

A slightly improved version would trigger the initial selection (to avoid having to set an initial class on each element):

```
$(function () {
    $(".colorSelect").change(function () {
        $(".color").removeClass("red, blue").addClass($(this).val());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qwrcxzat/4/

### Update:

If you do not want to hard-wire a list of the classes to remove you can also just iterate the list:

```
$(function () {
    $(".colorSelect").change(function () {
        $('option', this).each(function(){
            $(".color").removeClass($(this).val());
        });
        $(".color").addClass($(this).val());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qwrcxzat/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the '.' on the jQuery selector.

```
$(function() {
  $(".colorSelect").change(function() {
    $(".color").attr('class', ''); // See selector on this line
    $(".colorSelect").each(function() {
      $(".color").addClass($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This could never works as you remove all class on the element then expect to target it again with a selector! The question is *why do you have any upvotes*? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select id='dropdown'>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="grey">grey</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
</select>




$("#dropdown").on("change",function(e){  
         $("body").css('color',$("#dropdown option:selected").attr("value"));
    });
```

onchange of the select box the color property of body elements will change. Please add the javascript code in document.ready wrapper

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.